# Display on Mobile option not showing on component to re-enable component to display on mobile

Tags: community, mobile

I have a Community with a component that I marked as "Don't display on mobile."  It is not displaying via a mobile device.  However, I now want to display it on a mobile device and do not see the option to make it display.  The checkbox option to disable it from displaying does not appear on the component's properties anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by

- Use the Community Builder option to display the page in a mobile view
- Click on the page's Page Structure
- Click on the component you want to make visible
- Click on the visibility icon
- Publish the Community